# Create statement is not workin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oncreate

So I have a relationship of project to categories, such that a project can have many categories and a category belongs to a project. I have managed to have it working, but now - when I restartded my rails server, it doesn't work. The code I show bellow is what I had before the restarted and after the restart of my rails server, so I think its something to do with the code...

So I am not sure if you need models or just the controller or the form or what, so I have posted the create method from the categories controller as thats where the issue is happening:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @category = @project.categories.create(params[:category].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    if @category.save
      redirect_to project_tasks_path(@project.id), :flash => {:success => 'Created a Category! Now you can create tasks!'}
    else
      redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => 'We could not create an category. You need to enter a name.'}
    end
  end
```

It happens on the psychical create line, throwing the error:

```
 RuntimeError in CategoriesController#create

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Rails.root: /home/adam/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/StartPoint
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:14:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qbJyilRiMtwOyPDq9HQFO4JME+TPkh/cCEEqPZPxGDw=",
 "category"=>{"category"=>"ffffffff"},
 "commit"=>"Create Category",
 "project_id"=>"2"}
```

This is thrown upon hitting create. Any ideas or do I need to show more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `current_user` so it is set to `nil`.

Calling `.id` on `nil` will result in this error in Rails.

If your application does not allow anonymous access then you have a problem.
If it does, you should do this:

```
current_user ||= User.new
```

To always init `current_user` to a new User instance.
Your code will still not work as User.new will create a unsaved instance.